# I have this little "graph" where I want to add a title on top and a short description below. How can I do that?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=gray!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node, ellipse] (1) {{\scriptsize {Reputation1}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (2) [below= 30pt of 1] {{\scriptsize { Reputation2}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (3) [shift=(60:2) of 1] {{\scriptsize { Reuse small CRA}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (4) [shift=(10:5) of 1] {{\scriptsize { Behavior Intention small CRA}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (5) [shift=(-10:5) of 1] {{\scriptsize { Brand Preference}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (6) [below= 80pt of 4] {{\scriptsize { Behavior Intention large CRA}}};
  \node[main node, ellipse] (7) [below= 130pt of 3] {{\scriptsize { Reuse large CRA}}};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
  (1) edge node [left] {{\tiny H1.1b}} (2)
  (1) edge [right] node [left] {\begin{tiny} H3.1a\end{tiny}} (3)
  (1) edge node [below] {{\tiny H3.2a}} (4)
  (1) edge node [below] {{\tiny \ H3.3a}} (5)
  (2) edge [right] node [above] {\begin{tiny} H3.3b\end{tiny}} (5)
  (2) edge node [above] {{\tiny H3.2b}} (6)
  (2) edge node [left] {{\tiny H3.1b}} (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Your MWE is a `standalone`, do you want to import the output in the main document as a figure?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it as part of the `tikzpicture`, just add two nodes at appropriate locations. You could for example use the `north` and `south` anchors of the predefined `current bounding box` node, as in the example below.

I also took the liberty of modifying your code a bit. For example, you had a font size setting (`\Large`) in your `main node` style, but then you added `\scriptsize` to every single node that used the style. Same for the `ellipse` option. Much tidier to just modify the `main node` style.

Similarly for the edges, you have `\scriptsize` in the `every node` style, but you add `\tiny` everywhere.

Note also, that in `shift=(theta:r) at 1`, the `at 1` part does precisely nothing, `shift` is not relative to another coordinate, like `below` etc. In this case you get the desired result because the default coordinate is `(0,0)`, so the nodes `1`, `3`, `4` and `5` are placed at `(0,0)`, and the `shift`s of the latter three moves them to a different coordinate.

You didn't specify any formatting requests for the title/description, so none are added, with the exception of a `text width` for the description node.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->,>=stealth',
  shorten >=1pt,
  auto,
  node distance=3cm,
  thick,
  main node/.style={ellipse,fill=gray!20,draw,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries}
]

  \node[main node] (1) {Reputation1};
  \node[main node] (2) [below= 30pt of 1] {Reputation2};
  \node[main node] (3) [shift=(60:2)] {Reuse small CRA};
  \node[main node] (4) [shift=(10:5)] {Behavior Intention small CRA};
  \node[main node] (5) [shift=(-10:5)] {Brand Preference};
  \node[main node] (6) [below= 80pt of 4] {Behavior Intention large CRA};
  \node[main node] (7) [below= 130pt of 3] {Reuse large CRA};
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny}]
  (1) edge node [left] {H1.1b} (2)
  (1) edge [right] node [left] {H3.1a} (3)
  (1) edge node [below] {H3.2a} (4)
  (1) edge node [below] {H3.3a} (5)
  (2) edge [right] node [above] {H3.3b} (5)
  (2) edge node [above] {H3.2b} (6)
  (2) edge node [left] {H3.1b} (7);

\node [above=2mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Some title};
\node [below=3mm,text width=6cm] at (current bounding box.south) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur etc. Foo bar baz and all that jazz.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey Torbjorn, thanks a lot for the help :-)